# How can I take the mean of a categorical binary variable in r?

Tags: r

```
# Creating the folds
nfold <- 10
x <- nrow(TrimCredit)
folds <- createFolds(factor(TrimCredit$Class), k = 10, list = FALSE)
TrimCredit$fold <- folds
ddply(TrimCredit, 'fold', summarise, prop = mean(Class)) #Making sure each fold has the same percentage of 1's and 0's (doesn't work when "Class" is a factor?)
falseNegative <- rep(0, nfold)
falsePositive <- rep(0, nfold)
miss = rep(0, nfold)
```

The "Class" column in my "TrimCredit" dataset is a column of 1's and 0's set as factors (as.factor(Class)). The ddply function will not work properly while "Class" is a factor. I tried prop = mean(as.numeric(Class)), but it did not return the correct percentage. I need the mean of "Class" (the percentage of 1's), but I can't figure out how because I need to keep it as a factor. Help please!

Comment: In general, you don't take the mean of a categorical variable (e.g. what is the mean color of a bag of M&Ms?) However, in general it is not possible to help with questions on here unless you provide a reproducible example, e.g. provide all or a subset of `TrimCredit` and anything else so that all the code above works in someone else's R session. Providing what you would like the output to look like is also needed and can speed the time to your question answered. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because a factor has two parts the levels which are *always* saved as a character vector and an index which is an integer.  Your levels are `c("0", "1")` and your index is a mixtures of 1s and 2s depending on whether you want the first level entry (1 -> 0) or the second entry (2 -> 1).

Taking `mean(Class)` makes no sense because R has no idea that your class values are numbers too.  `mean(as.numeric(Class))` doesn't work because this leaves you with the indexes only (e.g. the 1s and 2s.) - so you get the wrong answer.

With that info, there are a lot of ways to get the right answer

The solution that always works for numeric levels:

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(Class))
```

Taking `as.character` replaces all the indices with associated characters.  Once we do that, we can convert the characters to numeric 0s and 1s, and take the mean of those.

Because we know we're working with 0s and 1s, we can also take a short cut:

```
mean(as.numeric(Class)) - 1
```

This works because the difference between 2 and 1 is the same as the difference between 1 and 0.  This will not work in general.